# CI multiple pagination in one view,

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I try to use multiple pagination in codeigniter in the same view.
My controler is:

```
    public function gallery()
{

    $config1 = array();
    $config1["base_url"] = site_url("pages/gallery");
    $config1["total_rows"] = $this->pagination_model->video_count();
    $config1["per_page"] = 1;
    $config1["uri_segment"] = 3;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config1);

    $page1 = ($this->uri->segment(3,0)) ? $this->uri->segment(3,0) : 0;
    $data["videos"] = $this->pagination_model->fetch_video($config1["per_page"], $page);
    $data["links1"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $config2 = array();
    $config2["base_url"] = site_url("pages/gallery").'/'.$this->uri->segment(3,0);
    $config2["total_rows"] = $this->pagination_model->gallery_count();
    $config2["per_page"] = 3;
    $config2["uri_segment"] = 4;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config2);

    $page2 = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;
    $data["galleries"] = $this->pagination_model->fetch_gallery($config2["per_page"], $page2);
    $data["links2"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $this->template->gallery_view($data);
}
```

Pagination work ok on the first and second config, independence, but when i click page nr. 3 for ex. in pagination link1 on the pagination link2 go to nr. 3 (only page nr. content is OK), and on page 6 link1 but link 2 is incremented with +1.

Need to be on press click link1:

- link1  ------------  link2

  1   ----     curent_page_link2(default is link2 = '')

  2   ----    curent_page_link2

  3   ----     curent_page_link2

  3   ----     curent_page_link2

But i have on press click link1:

- link1  ----------    link2

  1    ----    curent_page_link2(default is link2 = '')

  2    ----    curent_page_link2(default is link2 = '')

  3    ----    curent_page_link2   **( need to be (default is link2 = '') but i have activ link2 = '2' content from link2='')**

  4    ----    curent_page_link2

  5    ----    curent_page_link2   **( need to be (default is link2 = '') but i have activ link2 = '3' content from link2='')**

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

I am not tested this. This may helps you. Use 'prefix' and 'suffix' for pagination in config1.

```
...

$config1 = array();
$config1["base_url"] = site_url("pages/gallery");
$config1["total_rows"] = $this->pagination_model->video_count();
$config1["per_page"] = 1;
$config1["uri_segment"] = 3;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$config1['prefix'] = '';
$config1['suffix'] = '/'.$this->uri->segment(4,0);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$this->pagination->initialize($config1);

...
```

Comment: Hi Arjun Raj. thank you for solution. I try something similar but i have bug on click first link. I think i have only one solution, do it with AJAX.